# Backup SQL Server 2008 DB without Full Text Catalog

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, back

I am trying to backup a SQL Server 2008 database without the FULL Text Catalog. I tried to remove full text catalog and indexes before backup like this:

```
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON table1
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON table2
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON table3


DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG DBFullTextCatalog
EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'disable'
```

It says all commands executed successfully, however, when I do backup I still get the full text files in the backup:

```
SET @BackupPath = @BackupPath + N'DB_17965_1_backup.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE [DB_17965_1]
TO  DISK = @BackupPath
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'DB_17965_1-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

results in

```
10 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
40 percent processed.
50 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
70 percent processed.
80 percent processed.
90 percent processed.
Processed 832 pages for database 'DB_17965_1', file 'CelebrityGet' on file 1.
Processed 8 pages for database 'DB_17965_1', file 'ftrow_CelebritygetFullTextCatalog' on file 1.
100 percent processed.
Processed 1 pages for database 'DB_17965_1', file 'CelebrityGet_log' on file 1.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 841 pages in 0.431 seconds (15.244 MB/sec).
```

Comment: Not programming-related -> belongs on Serverfault.com, where the DBA's and ServerAdmins hang out - you'll get better answers there

Comment: Can you select * from sys.fulltext_catalogs and confirm you don't have another catalog?

Comment: @u07ch
yes, select * from sys.fulltext_catalogs does not return any row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. I had to delete full text files manually from DB properties window before making the backup. The DROP statements never removed the files. That's weird!!